# BackgroundWorker weird case ( Program is not responding )

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a backgroundworker in my Windows Form application. But it is so weird that after _DoWork() is completed program is not responding and I can not do anything.

Here is what I'm doing.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    excelOperation(fileName);   
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog fDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    fDialog.Title = "Open Excel File";
    fDialog.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx";
    fDialog.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";

    if (fDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        fileName = fDialog.FileName;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

And excelOperation() is something which operates something with excel file.

When I don't use _DoWork(), I mean when I do not use BackgroundWorker, there is no problem.
I have no idea what is wrong.

**Edit - Whole Code : **

```
private void excelOperation(string sFile)
    {
        string str_merged = "";

        if (sFile != "")
        {
            int rCnt = 0;
            int cCount = 0;

            dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 3;
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Makina Kodu";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Malzeme Kodu";
            dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Üretilecek adet";

            try
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");//excel dil hatası için
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo dil;
                dil = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("tr-TR"); //toUpper türkçe karakter hatası için

                Excel.Application xlApp;
                Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
                Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
                Excel.Range range;
                //Excel.Range mergeRange;
                ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

                string str = "";

                xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
                xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(sFile, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
                xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(5);
                range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
                string[,] excelArray = new string[range.Rows.Count, range.Columns.Count];

                int temp = range.Rows.Count - 1;
                Fcount = range.Rows.Count;



                temp[] t = new temp[range.Rows.Count];

                for (rCnt = 3; rCnt <= range.Rows.Count; rCnt++)
                {
                    for (cCount = 1; cCount <= range.Columns.Count; cCount++)
                    {

                        str = (range.Cells[rCnt, 15] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();

                        if (str == "TOPL. ADET") // satırlar arasında ki siyah başlıkları ayırmak için
                        {
                            rCnt = rCnt + 2;
                            str = "123";
                        }


                        //değerimiz #N/A yani null ise a string değerini atıyoruz 
                        if (str == "-2146826246")
                        {
                            str = "herhangi bi string";
                        }
                        if (IsNumeric(str)) // değerimiz null ise IsNumeric fonk na yollayıp doğruluyoruz
                        {
                            if ((range.Cells[rCnt, cCount] as Excel.Range).Value2 != null && (range.Cells[rCnt, cCount] as Excel.Range).Value2 != "")
                            {
                                str = (range.Cells[rCnt, cCount] as Excel.Range).Value2.ToString();
                                excelArray[rCnt - 1, cCount - 1] = str;

                                if (cCount == 1) { t[rCnt - 3].col_A = str; }
                                if (cCount == 4) { t[rCnt - 3].col_B = "00001"; }
                                if (cCount == 15) { t[rCnt - 3].col_C = str; }

                                if (cCount == 1) { str_merged = str; } //merged cell leri hafızada tutuyoruz

                            }
                            else // hafızadaki merged cell leri array imze atıyoruz
                            {
                                if (cCount == 1) { t[rCnt - 3].col_A = str_merged; }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    string[] row = { t[rCnt - 3].col_A, t[rCnt - 3].col_B, t[rCnt - 3].col_C };
                    if (row[1] != null)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                        dr["malzeme"] = row[0];
                        dr["makine"] = row[1];
                        dr["miktar"] = row[2];
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                    int percentage = 0;
                    percentage = rCnt * 100 / range.Rows.Count;
                    backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(percentage);
                }

                bool hataVarMi = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (t[i].col_B == null || t[i].col_B == "")
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    DataSet ds = DBClass.Default.SelectCommand("select STOK_KODU from TBLSTSABIT where STOK_KODU = '" + t[i].col_B + "'");
                    if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                    {
                        hataVarMi = true;
                        textBox1.Text += t[i].col_B.ToString() + "\r\n";
                    }
                }
                if (hataVarMi)
                {
                    formHeight("buyuk");
                    groupBox1.Visible = true;
                    lblDurum.Text = "Mamul Kodu Hatası!";
                }
                else
                {
                    formHeight("kucuk");
                    btnNetsis.Enabled = true;
                    lblDurum.Text = "Veriler aktarıldı. Netsis'e kaydetme işlemi yapabilirsiniz. ";
                }
                btnDurdur.Visible = false;
                //xlApp.Application.Quit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                btnDurdur.Visible = false;
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 

        }
        return;
    }

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        excelOperation(fileName);   

    }
```

Comment: What are you doing in the method excelOperation? the main steps, are you doing anything with the UI elements?

Comment: You can hang your UI thread if you are locking some resource shared between main and background threads

Comment: Reading excel file and filling a datagridview.

Comment: are you using COM interop?

Comment: could be getting a crossthread exception somewhere like the first answer suggests... hard to say without seeing all your code... an endless loop is also possible, but your leaving everyone in the dark with incomplete code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not fill `DataGridView` in your background thread. Fill `DataTable` object or collection of custom objects. And assign it as `DataSource` to DataGridView on `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.

Sample:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog fDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
    //...
    if (fDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(fDialog.FileName);
}

private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = (string)e.Argument;
    // fill foos from excel
    List<Foo> foos = excelOperation(fileName);    
    e.Result = foos;
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, 
                                                  RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = (List<Foo>)e.Result;
}
```

Comment: Tried exactly what you say, but nothing changed.

Comment: @Mtok what's happening if you will comment DataSource assignment (but collection creation will stay in DoWork handler)? Do you use some other shared resources in background thread?

Comment: I'm connecting to SQL Server. May it be about that ?

Comment: @Mtok it could cause delay before you see results in datagrid, but if you are connecting to SQL Server in background thread, that should not freeze your UI

Comment: Ok @lazyberezovsky I put whole code about backgroundworker. Can you check it please ?

Comment: @Mtok you still have lot of UI related code in your background thread (adding columns to gridview, updating textboxes and labels) - you should remove all that code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to a similar issue:

[Problem with BackgroundWorker and COM interop](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/c3618c98-24b3-4aa6-ad32-61763cdee006/)

What if you create a thread manually and change the thread's apartment state?  Perhaps, this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are hanging the UI thread locking some UI controls inside  the  `excelOperation` method.

I see that you wrote you are filling a grid or something similar. How are you doing it? You should do the job on some background variables and, when the work finishes, assign it to the data source of the grid or wherever you need.

**EDIT:** just read lazyberezovsky answer